# how to select duplicate record as one record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
# eventId, scheduleId, description
'158', '264', 'test', 'test123',
'160', '266', 'Dummyy"  "xyz"
'160', '266', 'Dummyy1"  "xyz2"
'161', '267', 'list t"  "pqr"
'169', '267', 'list t"  "pqr"
```

this is my Table data i want to apply group by in this manner so that it find duplicate and give Single record as duplicate record like eventId , scheduleId and 160,266 its coming two time so i have take that as Sgine time and output should like this :

```
# eventId, scheduleId, description
'158', '264', 'test', 'test123',
'160', '266', 'Dummyy"  "xyz"
'161', '267', 'list t"  "pqr"
'169', '267', 'list t"  "pqr"
```

please suggest me how to apply query for this i have tried group by eventId,scheduleId  but its gives wrong data please suggest me

Comment: Please double check your expected output and share what you have tried so far

Comment: And also, which record do you want to remain in each group?

Comment: use DISTINCT in your query, but wait, isnt your last 2 output are the same?

Comment: sorry that was mistake but  where distinct i have to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the two fields, and pass them together to the group by
as following

```
select 
 id, 
 concat(`field1`,`field2`) as `together` 
from table_name 
group by together
```

Comment: @1000111 thanx this i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach. however it will be very slow:

```
SELECT TE_OM.EVENTID,
       TE_OM.SCHEDULEID,
       TE.DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLE_EVENT TE_OM,

  (SELECT EVENTID,
          SCHEDULEID,
          MAX(DESCRIPTION)MX_DESCRIPTION
   FROM TABLE_EVENT TE
   GROUP BY EVENTID,
            SCHEDULEID)TE_0
WHERE TE_OM.EVENTID=TE_0.EVENTID
  AND TE_OM.SCHEDULEID=TE_0.SCHEDULEID
  AND TE_OM.DESCRIPTION=TE_0.MX_DESCRIPTION
GROUP BY TE_OM.EVENTID,
         TE_OM.SCHEDULEID,
         TE.DESCRIPTION
```

Also I can see 4 columns in output but 3 columns in header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   yourtable b
                   WHERE  a.numb = b.numb
                          AND a.eventId = b.eventId
                          AND a.description > b.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check your desired output, Below query will return output as you shown in your question although you can try with another solution i.e. without using scheduleId in group by clause.

```
select * from tablename group by eventId, scheduleId;
```

Another thing you have mentioned wrong no of table column and data column. Please have a look.

Hope this will help.